# Equivalent weight of calcium phosphate

Tags: mole

In a reaction, calcium phosphate is producing calcium hydrogen phosphate. Then we have to find the equivalent weight of calcium phosphate in this process.

I tried as:

Oxidation number of calcium in calcium phosphate is $\frac43$ and in calcium hydrogen phosphate it is $1.$

So the equivalents of calcium phosphate is $(\frac13)(3)$

Equivalent weight should be $\frac{310}{1}$

Am I correct?

Comment: Work on this some more... The oxidation number of calcium is +2 in both salts. The equivalent weight is certainly not 310.

Comment: @MaxW so oxidation number of which element is changing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aditya is right that calcium is $\ce{Ca^{2+}}$ in both salts so calcium isn't changing its oxidation number. In fact there is no redox reaction at all. The reaction is:

$\ce{Ca3(PO4)2 + 2H^+ -> 2CaHPO4 + Ca^{2+}}$

So for one mole of the $\ce{Ca3(PO4)2}$ reacts with 2 moles of $\ce{H+}$ so  1/2 mole of $\ce{Ca3(PO4)2}$ reacts per mole of $\ce{H+}$. Thus the equivalent weight of  $\ce{Ca3(PO4)2}$ is 1/2 of its molecular weight.

eq wt = $\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot 310.2 = 155.1 $

**NOTE**

*[Equivalent weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_weight) is sort of a peculiar notion and is sometimes not unique. So the use of equivalent weight has fallen out of favor. Look at this redox reaction with the permanganate ion*

$\ce{8 H+ + MnO4^- + 5e− -> Mn^{2+} + 4 H2O}$

*There are 8 $\ce{H+}$ ions but 5 $\ce{e^-}$, so should the molecular weight of the permanganate ion be divided by 8 or 5 to get the equivalent weight?*

Answer (score 1):

Calcium phosphate is $\ce{Ca3(PO4)2}$. The oxidation state of calcium is $+2$ here.

Calcium hydrogen phosphate is $\ce{CaHPO4}$. The oxidation state of calcium is also $+2$ here.

The equivalent weight of a salt is calculated by $\frac {\text{molecular weight of salt}} {\text{charge on the anion or cation}}$.

$$\ce{2 Ca3(PO4)2 -> 6 Ca^2+ + 4 (PO4)^3-}$$

Molar mass of calcium phosphate = $310~\mathrm{g}~\mathrm{mol}^{-1}$.

Equivalent weight = $\displaystyle \frac {2 \times 310} {6 \times 2}$ which gives you around $51~\mathrm{g}$.

Comment: But the answer given as 155 g

Comment: @user123733 Can you please post the reaction in the question?

Comment: There is no reaction given

Comment: @MaxW has given the right answer. The equation which he mentioned was what I expected. Equivalent weight is a tricky business. For the same compound, there can be different equivalent weights possible according to the reactions it participates in.